# Python visualizing optimization parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scipy, data-visualization

I have the following code where I iterate through a grid of 2 parameters in order to see which set of parameters will yield the best result.

```
from sklearn.grid_search import ParameterGrid

ar1= np.arange(1,10,0.1)
ar2= np.arange(0.1,3,0.01)
param_grid = {'p1': ar1, 'p2' : ar2}
grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
result=[]
p1=[]
p2=[]

for params in grid:
     r = getresult(params['p1'], params['p2'])
     result.append(r)
     p1.append(params['p1'])
     p2.append(params['p2'])
```

As a result I get 3 arrays, one with the result of every iteration and two arrays (p1,p2) with the corresponding parameters. I would now like to plot this data with matplotlib to visualize how the result varies across the parameter plane.

I tried the following but i got a blank plot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(p1, p2, result)
```

Ideally I would like to be able to create something like the plot below. How can I accomplish this with matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i tried the following but i got a blank plot:        fig = plt.figure() /
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')  /                                             ax.plot_surface(p1, p2, result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with the following solution:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The above yielded the desired visualization, as seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`plot_surface` requires the input arrays to be two-dimensional. As I interprete it, your arrays are 1D. So reshaping them into 2D could be a solution.

```
import numpy as np
shape = (len(ar2), len(ar1))
p1 = np.array(p1).reshape(shape)
p2 = np.array(p2).reshape(shape)
result = result.reshape(shape)
```

Then plotting it via

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(p1, p2, result)
```

might work. (I cannot test it at the moment.)